# Running a ceiling fan/light from another light in bathroom

Tags: ceiling-fan, fans

I have an older electrical panel with fuses. Can I take a wire from the small light over the medicine cabinet to run a fan and ceiling light also?

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to take at least two wires, a hot and a neutral, ground if there. If you paralled the small light, the fan and light would only go on with the switch. If the power source is at that light, then you could tap off it and use the pull chains or remote to operate the fan and light. You'd need some NM cable or conduit depending on the house wiring. Pictures of your panel and small light junction box are always nice, we might see something that needs correction.

Comment: Possible the OP meant cable when they said wire.  Would make it easier to help.

Comment: Also, it depends if the fan is going to be above the tub/shower.